# how to create a flow generator in python for my custom data

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, generator, training-data

I do a cat/dog binary classification
I created a training data this way, I applied an average filter to the images.
the problem is that the database is quite large and I get displayed right after that, your notebook tried to allocate more memory than is available. I read that generators in python take less disk memory and can solve this problem, but I don't know how to create a generator suitable for this code I just created as training data

```
train_dir = "../input/dog-cat/train"

CATEGORIES = ["dog", "cat"]
    
training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:  

        path = os.path.join(train_dir,category)  
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  

        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):  
            try:
                img_train = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
                img_mean = cv2.blur(reduced_img_train,(9,9))
                training_data.append([img_mean, class_num])  
            except Exception as e:
             pass
create_training_data()

import random
random.shuffle(training_data)

x_train=[]
y_train=[]

for features,label in training_data:
    x_train.append(features)
    y_train.append(label)
```

Answer (score 1):

with the requirements you want to use ImageDataGenerator() with blur functions, check out CV2 [CV2.blur()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-blur-method/). You can do it by the provided custom function " preprocessing_function=custom_image_preprocess " parameter in ImageDataGenerator() itself.

Sample: CV2 using standard deviations when you can do it with a custom function or just the same image channels order ( one hidden technique for reconstructable data in the kickboxing colors game ).

```
import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
BATCH_SIZE = 1
IMG_HEIGHT = 32
IMG_WIDTH = 32
IMG_CHANNELS=3
seed=42

directory = "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\example\\image\\"

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Definition / Class
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def custom_image_preprocess( image ):
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        image,
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array( image )
    img_1 = tf.keras.utils.array_to_img(img_array)
    
    temp = tf.concat([ tf.constant( img_array[:,:,0], shape=(img_array.shape[0], img_array.shape[1], 1) ), tf.constant( 150 - img_array[:,:,1], shape=(img_array.shape[0], img_array.shape[1], 1) ) ], axis=2)
    image = tf.concat([ tf.constant( temp[:,:,:], shape=(img_array.shape[0], img_array.shape[1], 2) ), tf.constant( 0.25 * img_array[:,:,2], shape=(img_array.shape[0], img_array.shape[1], 1) ) ], axis=2)

    return image


def train_image_gen():

    n_zoom_range = tf.where( tf.math.greater_equal( tf.constant( ( 1.0 * IMG_WIDTH ) / ( IMG_HEIGHT * 4 ), dtype=tf.float32 ), tf.constant( 0.25, dtype=tf.float32 ) ), ( 1.0 * IMG_WIDTH ) / ( IMG_HEIGHT * 4 ), 0.25 ).numpy()
    n_rotation_range = tf.where( tf.math.greater_equal( tf.constant( ( 1.0 * IMG_WIDTH ) / ( IMG_HEIGHT * 4 ), dtype=tf.float32 ), tf.constant( 0.25, dtype=tf.float32 ) ), ( 1.0 * IMG_WIDTH ) / ( IMG_HEIGHT * 4 ) * 100, 27.25 ).numpy()
    n_rescale = tf.where( tf.math.less_equal( tf.constant( 1.0 / ( IMG_WIDTH + IMG_HEIGHT )), tf.constant( 125.0 )), tf.constant( 1.0 / ( IMG_WIDTH + IMG_HEIGHT )).numpy(), 125.0 ).numpy()

    train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        # shear_range=0.2,
        # zoom_range=float(n_zoom_range),
        # horizontal_flip=True,
        validation_split=0.2,
        # rotation_range=float(n_rotation_range),
        # rescale=float(n_rescale),
        
        # rescale=1./255,
        # featurewise_center=False,
        # samplewise_center=False,
        # featurewise_std_normalization=False,
        # samplewise_std_normalization=False,
        # zca_whitening=False,
        # zca_epsilon=1e-06,
        # rotation_range=0,
        # width_shift_range=0.0,
        # height_shift_range=0.0,
        # brightness_range=None,
        # shear_range=0.0,
        # zoom_range=0.0,
        # channel_shift_range=0.0,
        # fill_mode='nearest',
        # cval=0.0,
        # horizontal_flip=False,
        # vertical_flip=False,
        # rescale=None,
        preprocessing_function=custom_image_preprocess
        # data_format=None,
        # validation_split=0.0,
        # interpolation_order=1,
        # dtype=None
        # https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator
        
        )
        
    train_image_ds = train_generator.flow_from_directory(
        directory,
        target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        class_mode='binary',    # None  # categorical   # binary
        subset='training',
        color_mode='rgb',       # rgb   # grayscale
        seed=seed,
        )
        
    return train_image_ds

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS )),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS)),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((30, 30, 32)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
) # 0.00001

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(train_image_gen(), validation_data=train_image_gen(), batch_size=100, epochs=50 )

input( '..;.' )
```

Output: Training with ImageGenerator, please monitor resources usages as the objective.

```
Found 16 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/50
2022-11-26 23:00:06.112861: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:368] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
16/16 [==============================] - 9s 146ms/step - loss: 1.1202 - accuracy: 0.4375 - val_loss: 0.7060 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 57ms/step - loss: 0.7892 - accuracy: 0.3125 - val_loss: 0.6961 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/50
 3/16 [====>.........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6903 - accuracy: 0.6667T
```

- [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixd6b.png)
- [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR8fe.png)